# Thread High CPU Usage but at State of "Ready"

Tags: windows, multithreading, cpu

I am using Process Explorer in Windows to examine a process.

When I look at the thread tab within Properties of this process I see 1 thread with high CPU usage (~30-49% total CPU of a dual core server, so it using a large amount of CPU time if you equate that single thread to a single CPU times worth of an interval).

Now if I sit an observe this thread it spends 98% of it's time at the state of "Ready" where the other time it is of state "Running". To illustrate this better in terms of an interval:

```
t=0, CPU = 35, State = Ready 
t=1, CPU = 49, State = Ready 
t=2, CPU = 50, State = Ready 
t=3, CPU = 39, State = Ready 
t=4, CPU = 32, State = Ready 
t=5, CPU = 35, State = Ready 
t=6, CPU = 37, State = Running
t=7, CPU = 40, State = Ready 
t=8, CPU = 42, State = Ready 
t=9, CPU = 43, State = Ready
```

How can this thread be using this much CPU when at the state of Ready?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This is standard Heisenberg at work, what you see is affected by the act of observing it.  In order for Process Explorer to make a snapshot of the running threads, it needs to itself acquire the processor.  Which makes it less likely, especially on a 2 core processor, that another thread could be busy executing.  "Ready" means that the thread is active, it just didn't get a chance to acquire the processor at the moment the snapshot was made.

State can only get reliable on a many-core processor.  The kind that Mark Russinovich uses :)

Comment: +1, sounds good to me, though I wonder why, if the procexp snapshot-thread is running, the heavy-CPU thread is not running more often on the other core.  Maybe procexp runs two snapshot-threads, one for each core?

Comment: Thank you very much for the speedy reply. I will check on a server with more cores and will get back to you!